# How to get a reference in cell instead of value

Tags: vba, variables, range, formula

Column A contains address of a relevant cell 
     for example A1 is pointing to B15
                 A2 is pointing to B3, etc, etc
Column B contains Data (numbers) some of them are bold

I'm trying to make a macro that will apply bold to relevant fields in A column.
In order to do that I created a loop that checks cells in col. A one by one, and find outs that address of corresponding cell in column B is bold.

I need to read reference to cell in B column and translate it to a range variable so I can check it's properties in column B

any ideas how to do that ? I'm new

Answer (score 0):

For each cell in column A, enumerate cells in its [`.DirectPrecedents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839667.aspx) and see if any is bold.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to retrieve the formula in the first cell, from this you instantiate a range object with the formula. Then with `finalRange` you can then check property values such as Font.Bold:

```
Dim initialRangeFormula As String
Dim finalRange As Range

    initialRangeFormula = Range("A1").Formula

    Set finalRange = Range(initialRangeFormula)

    Debug.Print finalRange.Font.Bold
```